# New worksheet is not created in a existing workbook using phpSpreadSheet library

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I have a template excel sheet saved as `template.xls`.I'm trying to get it's copy of the `template` sheet into another workbook. below is my code ,

```
   $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::
                    load('report/dailyReport_Line'.$_REQUEST['line'].'_'.$year.'_'.$month.'.xls');

    $template = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load('template.xls');

    $clonedWorksheet = clone $template->getSheetByName('template');
    $clonedWorksheet->setTitle($date);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($clonedWorksheet);
```

when i go to the corresponding $spreadsheet file,the copied excel file is not updated. I'll appreciate if someone could assist me to solve it

Comment: exists the variable $date and Worksheetname template in exact this spelling?